# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Please help me find the guidelines that were not followed when asking this question.

[If jet engines did leave chemtrails, wouldn't the chemicals cause adverse reactions in the engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/chemtrail-conspiracy-via-jet-engine-feasibility)

I have read the guidelines for this site, and have been participating in SE sites since 2011.  How does this not pertain to aviation?  How does it belong on another site?  What guidelines were broken?

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't vote on this. That said, being primarily about a conspiracy theory, your question strikes me as most appropriate for Skeptics.SE.

Comment: We have [already](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8402/do-airplanes-release-biological-or-chemical-agents-forming-trails) [covered](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/191/do-contrails-last-long-enough-to-explain-chemtrails) chemtrails on [skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), but if you have another question not already answered feel free to ask.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but did you read the question? My goal in asking the question is to get opinions from educated people regarding how said 'chems' would negatively effect jet turbine engines.  Please read deeper than the word 'conspiracy'. It has been re-opened, since skeptics does not answer my question explicitly (would chems destroy jet engines.. the only question I am asking). So no, you haven't addressed my question, and yes, its appropriate and suitable for aviation. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Good question, all five people who voted to close said that it was off-topic (so at least there was a consensus for the reason).

At the moment, our [On Topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help area is a little light (e.g. no help at all).  There is a meta question that we can look at for right now though:  [What topics can I ask about here?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/282/69)  This question seems to fall into a couple of the topics mentioned as allowed, such as aircraft systems and technology.

Perhaps it had more to do with the wording of the question.  I personally feel that it is okay, but borderline too broad just because you asked about so many different things in one question.

I suspect that you would have gotten a different response if you had asked the question more along the lines of:  "Would adding barium to jet fuel cause damage to the engines?"  This wouldn't carry the negative connotation of being associated with the conspiracy theorists (who have a general image of being a little...  unstable) and would probably attract more expert opinions.

Perhaps try focusing more on the actual question that you have without the extra background (and maybe limiting the scope to a smaller number of substances)  and see if it is reopened.

Comment: Agreed 100%. I was going to write up an answer much like this, but I'm too slow.

Comment: After receiving a second upvote on the question this morning (concensus it was actually a good question), I have edited with a disclaimer and voted to reopen.

Comment: That looks a lot better, and I reopened the question since I agree with the others who voted to reopen.