# Should we answer non-aviation aerodynamics questions?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/specifically-what-does-noise-refer-to-in-wind-turbine-design) is about aerodynamics but has nothing to do with aviation: it relates to wind turbines. Should we answer questions that are about aerodynamics but not aviation?

In the meta question [about what is considered on-topic](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/282/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here/286#286) here, the highest voted [answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/286/62) proposes that aerodynamics is only on-topic when it directly relates to aviation:

> Aerodynamics related to aircraft

If we don't want to answer general aerodynamics questions then one option is to direct questioners to [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com); both physics.SE and aviation.SE have an aerodynamics tag. Currently physics has 204 questions with that tag and aviation has 108 (although we can't really compare those numbers directly since the sites are completely different).

Answer (score 10):

If we take on wind turbines, will we have to take on sailing and wind surfing aerodynamics as well? I think those questions belong in Physics

Comment: I'm not sure they belong in Physics, but I agree they don't belong *here* -- While a wind turbine and a propeller are similar beasts the only aviation-related aspect of a wind turbine is "You probably don't want to fly your aircraft into one!"

Comment: Physics mod here - we can definitely take at least some of these questions, but I _think_ in most cases they won't be suitable for migration as written. Rather it would be better to recommend that the OP refocus the question on the underlying physical principle(s), strip any aviation-specific terminology, and make a new post on [physics.SE]. If you do migrate a question, we'd appreciate a mod flag so we can check it (if it's not on topic, we close it; no big deal), and you can always ask for feedback on individual questions in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71).

Comment: @DavidZ -- oops, guess I failed to do that w/ a recent question I posted to Physics SE... Good to read that comment.

Answer (score 7):

I think that aerodynamics is such an integral part of aviation that we have experts in the field who can be helpful and provide knowledge which is somewhat cross-discipline.

For instance, Aerodynamic questions about the turbine blades themselves would probably be very similar to questions about propellers and useful on an aviation site. Other types of questions about wind turbines, like maybe electrical generation or electronic control questions would probably be completely off topic.

I think that it depends and we should address them on a case by case basis using the voting system as designed.