# Why was this regulations question without a jurisdiction reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

This is about [Can I fly a friend for money when holding a commercial pilot certificate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/89284/can-i-fly-a-friend-for-money-when-holding-a-commercial-pilot-certificate?noredirect=1)

We have many questions on the topic, but OP did not say which country. A comment was left asking 'for which country?', and until this is clarified, the standard procedure is to put it *on hold.* Which took place, but rather due to a duplicate.

> [image]
> "Vote to close questions that could be improved"

Then a non-OP edit made it general and applicable to all jurisdictions, which means it's not well-defined, and basically any answer goes (*including* those already covered in other posts). And it [was reopened](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/89284/timeline). I can't vote to close *again.* I **understand the good faith motive** of trying to keep a question open, but this IMO is an unintentional well-meaning disservice. If a question omits an important detail, it needs to be added by OP, more so here **since dupes exist.**

Also any such past questions that may have fallen through the cracks from e.g. seven years ago, should not be ideally used as precedents that overrule how the site is supposed to operate.

What should be done about it?

BTW I only bring this up because it was bumped today by another edit that doesn't add anything.

---

Related:

- [Remove regulation tag while we still can?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/66/14897)
- [How can we best tackle the reviewing discrepancy?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3978/14897)

---

#### Update

Thanks to everyone who read the post and took action, the post is now closed after two weeks of being in review and of close votes expiring. And the total score went from +3 to -1, allowing the site's roomba (`bot`) to do its job; the post was automatically deleted on the 23rd of Oct.